# Android View Animation - multiple animations parallel execution issue

Tags: android, android-animation, viewanimator

I am trying to create an animation which is combination of different animations like translate from bottom to top and then 2 animations together for rotation and alpha. For me translate is working fine but rotation and alpha are not working. They are not even working individually outside . To achieve i am using below mentioned animation set :

```
<target android:name="group1_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="300"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="translateY"
                android:valueFrom="500"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="group1_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                android:shareInterpolator="true">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:propertyName="rotation"
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:toDegrees="90"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:propertyName="alpha"
                    android:fromAlpha="0"
                    android:toAlpha="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
```

Comment: AnimatorSet does not always work as expected. Look into the ViewPropertyAnimator class which allows you to chain multiple animations together, you should be available to achieve your animation in one line of Java/Kotlin Code

Comment: Thanks A Honey Bustard I have read the documentation for ViewPropertyAnimator. Will try to implement using that